# Long_Live_Access_Token, API How to?

Tags: python, facebook

i was trying to get a long live access token for Facebook in python.

this is the code i found:

```
from facepy.utils import get_extended_access_token

app_id = 'xxx'
app_secret = 'yyy'

short_lived_access_token = "Token"

LONG_LIVE_ACCESS_TOKEN, expires_at = get_extended_access_token(
          short_lived_access_token,
          app_id, app_secret)

f = open("f.txt","w")
f.write(LONG_LIVE_ACCESS_TOKEN)
print expires_at
```

The main problem that if i put the code it generate in my program, the following error appears:

```
facepy.exceptions.FacebookError: [100] API calls from the server require an appsecret_proof argument
```

From what i understand, this means that i'm using the token in the wrong way. 
How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the library does, but the documentation at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests#appsecret_proof

contains information on how to use the `appsecret_proof`.

Otherwise, Access Tokens can also be extended with plain HTTP GET calls, as explained at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending